# Best databasing practice for tracing non-homogenous events

Tags: database, data-structures, nosql, database-schema

Suppose I have the the following event data scheme:

```
event_record_unique_id: long
event_timestamp: long
session_id: long
event_id: int
event_data: data  # concrete type depends on event_id
```

... so, the contents of the data may depend on, let's say 500, event_ids, leading to 200 different concrete data types for "data". For example:

```
{
   event_record_unique_id: 17126721
   event_timestamp: 1234
   session_id: 3452
   event_id: 50
   event_data: {
       user_id: 123
       page_id: 789
   }
}
{
   event_record_unique_id: 1712672123
   event_record_unique_id: 17126723
   event_timestamp: 1234
   session_id: 3454
   event_id: 51
   event_data: {
       user_id: 124
       button_id: 789
   }
}
{
   event_timestamp: 1234
   session_id: 3454
   event_id: 51
   event_data: {
       crash_report: "text"
       device_id: "12312"
   }
}
```

Also:

- many of the event_data attributes appear in many of the concrete event_data objects
- I need to perform indexed searches on some of the event_data attributes (e.g. find me all the records where user_id=X )
- there's a continuing need to keep on adding event types and new attributes
- the above data structure is always trivially flattened so that a single record can be represented equivalently as a row with N columns where (and attributes name/type collision
   are solved by renaming attributes).

The naive RDBMS approach would involved making ~500 tables (one per concrete type of "data"). I've discounted this approach (= excessive waste of human effort in modelling). Plus, I cannot easily search all records over user_id (since user_id appears in very many tables).

Flattening the structure in an RDBMS is also quite costly (N-8 of the elements are NULL and contain no information).

Mongodb-type document database solutions appear to be a good, however, space costs seems quite high if attribute names are held with each record, not much better than an RDBMS. However, this does allow me to index by fields in the data object.

For me, an ideal data representation of this would be a table that is optimized to allow rows with many null elements (e.g. by keeping an active column bitmask per row). Or a document DB in which a document collection maintains a library of document schemas used enable compacting the data (and each document having reference to its schema).

What kind of database would people recommend for the above example case?

Comment: About how many events will you need to track at any given point in time?

Comment: 10 or 20 a second? Each consisting of one of 500 or so concrete event types.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server 2008 and up have [Sparse Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx). Up to 30,000 can be added in a table, and they can be indexed (filtered indexes are recommended). Or so says BOL, I have not used them myself. This would results in a single very large table that might support what you need.

With that said, I don't know it would be particularly efficient. Some math:

- Assume 10 rows a second
- becomes 10*60*60*24 = 864,000 rows a day
- or 315,360,000 rows a year
- with a *very* rough over-estimate of 50 bytes a row
- is about 14GB a year
- for how many years do you have to keep the data?
- and double that if it's more like 20 rows per second

So storage doesn't seem too way out of line... but I don't know, you want to work up some serious size projection factors. And that's just storage, what do you want or need to *do* with the data? Is retrieval time for specified rows important? What about analysis and data mining? I'm a SQL guy through and through, and I think it could be done, but this pretty much is the kind of problem that Hadoop and NoSQL solutions were devised for, and it could well be worth your time to thoroughly investigating those options.